# What does it mean to have a question immediately marked duplicate by "Community"?

Tags: discussion

Just curious.  I marked [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/166960/1322) as a duplicate an hour or so ago, and came back later to see if it had indeed been closed.  It had, and I expected to see a list of names after mine, or at least one more name besides mine, i.e. a moderator.

Instead what it said was "marked as duplicate by tcrosley, Community"

What does Community mean in this context?  I've never seen that before.

I know that Community magically brings back unanswered questions to the active list every so often, and she (somehow seems like a she) "owns" Community Wiki answers.  Not sure what else her superpowers are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A (new) feature is that if you suggest that a question is a duplicate, the original asker can agree with you and the question will be closed immediately (as a duplicate).

Meta.SE link describing the UI and behavior: 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/161579

Comment: wouldnt it make more sense then to mention the asker in the list then?